# How to use an object that got return in another class

Tags: java

I have this class, that returns an object, if the email, password and category (enum) are correct:

```
public class LoginManager {

    private static LoginManager instance = new LoginManager();

    private LoginManager() {
        super();

    }


    public static LoginManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public ClientFacade login(String email, String password, ClientType clientType) throws SQLException {
        if (clientType == ClientType.Administrator) {
            AdminFacade adminFacade = new AdminFacade();
            if (adminFacade.login(email, password) == true) {
                return adminFacade;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (clientType == ClientType.Company) {
            CompanyFacade companyFacade = new CompanyFacade();
            if (companyFacade.login(email, password) == true) {
                return companyFacade;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (clientType == ClientType.Customer) {
            CustomerFacade customerFacade = new CustomerFacade();
            if (customerFacade.login(email, password) == true) {
                return customerFacade;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

How do I use that object in another class?
This is the other class, that is supposed to use the object that return:

```
public class Test {

    CouponsDBDAO coupDBD = new CouponsDBDAO();

    CouponExpirationDailyJob dailyJob =
            new CouponExpirationDailyJob(coupDBD, false);

    LoginManager Log = LoginManager.getInstance();


    public void testAll() {

        try {
            Log.login("admin@admin.com", "admin", ClientType.Administrator); {

            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

How do I use now the adminFacade for example?

Comment: `ClientFacade  cf = Log.login("admin@admin.com", "admin", ClientType.Administrator); if(cf instanceof AdminFacade){..} //do your stuff here`

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? Your `login()` method is returning an object you can check.

Comment: Variable/field names should start in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!! It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
LoginManager Log = new LoginManager(); 
public void testAll() {

    try {
        ClientFacade facade = Log.login("admin@admin.com", "admin", ClientType.Administrator); 
        facade.DoSomethingUseful();



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```